# Date Calcs , possible use of partition/row functions

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, teradata

I have a table containing invoice level data and I have a business request to create a table containing New Business dollars to be awarded to sales reps.

Here is the logic:

1. IF  no sales have been made to this customer in the past 6 months or if the customer is a new customer (not existing in the table), count sale as 'new business'.
2. New Business Credit will last for the next 3 months after first qualifying 'New Business' sale.

Table Structure (for sake of simplicity)

```
 Customer # - Invoice # - Invoice Dt - Total $$
```

Sounds simple enough but i'm having a bit of trouble framing it in sql. Any thoughts?

Comment: _"i'm having a bit of trouble framing it in sql"_ That implies you tried anything. Please show evidence of what you tried. As well as leading to more relevant answers, it also demonstrates that you've applied effort. You should also show the table structures, example input data, and desired output data. Please don't expect people to guess.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: "Create a table" does not mean anything here.  Do you mean a view?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the *results* that you want.  This is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Take this step by step

Prior Customers (More than 3 months but less than 6 months)

```
 SELECT CustomerNo
 FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_TELL_US
 WHERE InvoiceDt > CURRENT_DATE - 6 MONTHS -- newer than 6 months
   AND InvoiceDt < CURRENT_DATE - 3 MONTHS -- older than 3 months
```

Now take everything from the past 3 months that does not Include those

```
 CREATE VIEW NEW_CUSTOMERS AS 

 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_TELL_US
 WHERE InvoiceDt > CURRENT_DATE - 3 MONTHS -- newer than 3 months
  AND CustomerNo NOT IN (
   SELECT CustomerNo
   FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_TELL_US
   WHERE InvoiceDt > CURRENT_DATE - 6 MONTHS -- newer than 6 months
     AND InvoiceDt < CURRENT_DATE - 3 MONTHS -- older than 3 months
 )
```

You could also do this with a join.